# php variable in array problem

Tags: php, arrays, variables

whats wrong with this picture?

```
$appleVar = 'apple';
$veggie = 'carrots';

$var = array('fruit' => $appleVar, 'veggie' => ''.$carrotVar.' no carrots please');

print_r($var);
```

when I print the array only "no carrots please" is displayed. why?

I'm so sorry I meant

```
$carrotVar = 'carrots'; not $veggie = 'carrots';
```

Comment: where does $carrotVar come from? or should that be $veggie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring the array, you are using `$carrotVar` :

```
$var = array(
    'fruit' => $appleVar, 
    'veggie' => ''.$carrotVar.' no carrots please'
);
```

But **that `$carrotVar` variable is not defined**.

You should probably use the `$veggie` variable :

```
$var = array(
    'fruit' => $appleVar, 
    'veggie' => ''.$veggie.' no carrots please'
);
```

Or rename it so it matches its content :

```
$carrotVar = 'carrots';
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$veggie = 'carrots';
```

to

```
$carrotVar = 'carrots';
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked carefully.

In my case it is printing :-

```
Notice: Undefined variable: carrotVar in /home/jatin/webroot/vcms/trunk/application/modules/ibroadcast/controllers/VideoController.php on line 10 Array (
    [fruit] => apple
    [veggie] =>  no carrots please )
```

Comment: Since there is no carrotVar defined it is throwing notice also

Answer (score 1):

Although php doesn't need variable declaration, you can simply use it just by defining it when needed by the variable you are using, i.e. `$carrotVar` has no value in it so the output is being displayed not as you wished just switch `$veggie = 'carrots';` to `$carrotVar = 'carrots';` or change the array variable.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `$carrotVar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$appleVar = 'apple';  
$veggie = 'carrots';  
$carrotVar = $veggie . ' no carrots please';  
$var = array('fruit' => $appleVar, 'veggie' => $carrotVar);
```

(or whatever your output needs to be.)